# Class Inheritance producing wrong output

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class Employee:

    raise_amt = 1.04 # 4% raise
    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.fname = first
        self.lname = last
        self.salary = pay
        self.email = first.lower()+'.'+last.lower()+'@email.com'
        Employee.num_of_emps+=1
    
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.fname,self.lname)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.salary = self.raise_amt*self.salary

    

class Manager(Employee):

    raise_amt = 1.3  # 30% raise in salary

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees
    
    def add_emp(self,emp):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)

    def remove_emp(self,emp):
        if emp in self.employees:
            self.employees.remove(emp)

    def print_emps(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            print('-->',emp.fullname())
```

```
emp_1 = Employee('John','Doe',5000)
emp_2 = Employee('Jane','Doe',1000)
mgr_1 = Manager('John','Wick',2000,[emp_1,emp_2])

print(mgr_1.email)
print(mgr_1.print_emps()) # <---- PRODUCING INCORRECT OUTPUT
```

---

Hi, I'm learning python's classes and inheritance. While applying what I learned, I got a minor wrong output. I tried to rectify it but no luck. Therefore, I request you to please help me.

The output of `print(mgr_1.print_emps())` should be:

```
--> John Doe
--> Jane Doe
```

But I am getting the output as:

```
--> John Doe
--> Jane Doe
None
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with inheritance, this happens because you are printing the returned value from `print_emps`, which is `None`. Just call the function without `print()`

```
print(mgr_1.email)
mgr_1.print_emps()
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't enclose your call with print, you here are trying to print the return value for "print_emps" which is "None" because you didn't return anything , instead you should remove you print call and just call the method

```
mgr_1.print_emps()
--> John Doe
--> Jane Doe
```